# Opening menu using position, angular2 material

Tags: angular, typescript, menu, angular-material, menuitem

I am doing a project in which i need to open the menu before x-position. I have added the code mentioned in [material.angular.io](https://material.angular.io/components/component/menu) but it is not working.

```
<p class="more" [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu">+7 others</p>

<md-menu xPosition="before" #menu="mdMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
   <span md-menu-item>Rahul</span>
   <span md-menu-item>Sneha</span>
</md-menu>
```

please tell me where i am going wrong?

Comment: have you added `angular-material` required files in your project ?

Comment: yes! `[overlapTrigger]="false"` is working!. Problem is only with position